# yui-css grid: how to get a 1/4 - 2/4 - 1/4 grid set up?

Tags: css, yui, yui-grids

I have been trying to get yui-css grid system to make a three column grid, where the first on (left) uses 1/4 of the space, the second (middle) uses 2/4 of the space and the third (right) uses 1/4 of the space.

Something like this:

```
|            header             |
-------- ------------------------    
| left  |     middle    | right |
--------------------------------
|            footer             |
```

Any input will be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Judging from the answers/comments, I realize some more info is needed.

- The site has a fixed with (750px - #doc in YUI).
- I am not really interested in none YUI solutions (thanks anyway), since I would love to start using YUI-CSS as a base framework, so this project I am doing is a test to see if it meets my needs. I like the fact that it works the same way across different browsers.

Comment: Do you need it to remain as a YUI framework option, or would you accept non-framework answers that achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using yui solution is quite tricky :) but below is ur solution to 1/4, 2/4, 1/4 column layout

```
<body>
  <div id="doc4" class="yui-t5">
    <div id="hd">
    </div> <!-- header -->
    <div id="bd">
      <div id="yui-main">
        <div class="yui-b">
          <div class="yui-gd">
            <div class="yui-u first">
              Left Column
            </div> <!-- yui-u first -->
            <div class="yui-u">
              Middle Column
            </div> <!-- yui-u -->
          </div> <!-- yui-gd -->
        </div> <!-- yui-b -->
      </div> <!-- yui-main -->
      <div class="yui-b">
        Right Column
      </div> <!-- yui-b -->
    </div> <!-- body -->
  </div> <!-- doc4 -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used yui's grid for fixed formats, but for resizable liquid layouts I prefer [this solution](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm). It sounds like you want to use percentages rather than a set number of pixels. Is there a reason you're using yui grid for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using general CSS/(X)HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
#wrapper {width: 100%; position: relative; }

#header {width: 100%;text-align: center; }

#left-col {width: 24%;  display: inline-block;}

#main-col {width: 48%; margin: 0 1%;  display: inline-block;}

#right-col {width: 24%;  display: inline-block;}

#footer {width: 100%; clear: both; text-align: center; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
    <h1>...header-content...</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="left-col">
    ...left-col content...
    </div>

    <div id="main-col">
    ...main-col content...
    </div>

    <div id="right-col">
    ...right-col content...
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    ...footer content...
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
    ...content...
    </div>

    <div id="left-col">
    ...content...
    </div>

    <div id="main-col">
    ...content...
    </div>

    <div id="right-col">
    ...content...
    </div>

</div>
```

This works, but it isn't particularly pretty, and you're still left to deal with the column heights and locations yourself.